# How to fetch contents of @ElementCollection table mapped via @MapKeyColumn

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa

There are many questions similar to this here but after a lot of looking, I have not found this question or an answer to it.

I have an entity with an `@ElementCollection` mapped like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    ...
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "value")
    @Column(name = "description")
    private Map<String, String> validValues = new HashMap<>();

    @Column
    protected Long otherId;
```

This configuration works fine, I did not specify a name for the mapped table but Hibernate created it automatically from the mapping and named it `my_entity_valid_values`.  Fetching these values via Hibernate works fine for each `MyEntity` instance, the problem is with performance for large data sets.

In my app, I can have large collections of `MyEntity` objects and rather than rely on Hibernate's eager fetching which produces `n` queries I would like to fetch them all myself.  I am trying this HQL:

```
select e.id,vv from MyEntity e join e.validValues vv where e.otherId=14
```

This results in the following SQL:

```
select
    myentity0_.id as col_0_0_,
    validvalue1_.description as col_1_0_ 
from
    my_entity myentity0_ 
inner join
    my_entity_valid_values validvalue1_ 
        on myentity0_.id=validvalue1_.my_entity_id 
where
    myentity0_.other_id=14
```

The `my_entity_valid_values` table as created by Hibernate has 3 columns, `my_entity_id` which is the foreign key back to the source table, and also `value` and `description` columns which are the two columns that represent the keys and values for the `Map<String, String>` mapping.

However, the SQL that is generated from the `vv` reference in the HQL only includes the `description` column, which omits the `value` column and provides an incomplete picture of this data.  How can I get both the `value` and `description` columns in this case?  I have tried HQL such as:

```
select e.id,vv.value,vv.description ...
```

But this gives me `org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element`.

Any tips welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993459/1218704) I figured this out, the answer is to reference the collection column with `index()` like this:

```
select e.id,index(vv),vv from MyEntity e join e.validValues vv where e.otherId=14
```

This adds the `value` column (in my case the column passed to `@MapKeyColumn`) and returns all of the data I need from the query.